# Haw can I add the caption to react-gallery-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to add the caption(text on the photo) to this photo-gallery component, but I can't find anywhere how to do that.

Here is npm site https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-photo-gallery

And this is the sandbox of that https://codesandbox.io/s/9yx911wl9y

Comment: Their readme mentions captions but there doesn't appear to be any documentation for them. Could you implement a [figcaption](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp) maybe? I've looked through the source code on the github quickly and cannot see any caption functionality, perhaps you will have to use another more suitable library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately not as easy as it could be to add captions using react-photo-gallery, but it's not insurmountable.

react-photo-gallery supports defining a custom image renderer, and you need to create one of these that knows what to do with captions. I did this today and posted [a simple example in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-qkcf4). Note that I added a `caption` to each image in photos.js, defined the custom image renderer in ImageWithCaption.js, and added some styling in styles.css.

Credits:

- I started from [this example of a custom renderer](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7o241q09) that's linked to from the docs.
- I picked up some styling info from [here](https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/)